# Grunt Errors on an EC2 Instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, gruntjs

I am trying to run a "grunt build" task on an EC2 instance that someone else set up.  For some reason, it is not running, and I'm pretty sure the task was run once before on the instance, a couple months ago.  I am getting the following Exception chain:

```
$ grunt build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 17, in <module>
    import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 15, in <module>
    import encodings
ImportError: No module named encodings
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 16, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ExpatError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyexpat import *
ImportError: No module named pyexpat

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 17, in <module>
    import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 15, in <module>
    import encodings
ImportError: No module named encodings
```

I've looked, and there is an "encodings" directory at /usr/lib/python2.7/:

```
drw-r--r--  2 root root  20480 Jul 27 20:20 encodings
```

And there is a "pyexpat.h" file at /usr/include/python2.7/:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2007 Feb 27 20:24 pyexpat.h
```

I tried reinstalling python with the following command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7` but that didn't fix the problem.  Neither does `sudo grunt build`, that gives me `Command not found`.  Any advice on fixing this is greatly appreciated.